# pyspark.sql.functions abs() fails with PySpark Column input

Tags: pyspark

I'm trying to convert the following HiveQL query into PySpark:

```
SELECT *
FROM ex_db.ex_tbl
WHERE dt >= 20180901 AND 
      dt < 20181001 AND
      (ABS(HOUR(FROM_UNIXTIME(local_timestamp))-13)>6 OR
      (DATEDIFF(FROM_UNIXTIME(local_timestamp), '2018-12-31') % 7 IN (0,6))
```

I am not great at PySpark, but I have viewed the list of functions. I have gotten to the point where I am attempting the ABS() function, but struggling to do so in PySpark. Here is what I have tried:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1.withColumn("abslat", F.abs("lat"))
An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.abs
```

It doesn't work. I read that the input must be a PySpark Column. I checked and that condition is met.

```
type(df1.lat)
<class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your passsing string to abs which is valid in case of scala with $ Operator which consider string as Column.
you need to use abs() method like this abs(Dataframe.Column_Name)
For your case try this one:
**df1.withColumn("abslat", abs(df1.lat))**

Answer (score 0):

Use `df1.withColumn("abslat", F.abs(F.col("lat")))`